# Disclosure button for displaying more text in a table view

Tags: iphone

So i have created a custom cell with IB and source files associated which is put in my table view. The cell in my table view display text which doesn't fit entirely. What i want is to add a disclosure button in my cells which when is touch up display the rest of the text of the cell in for example two lines or by adjusting the text in the cell. But i really do not know how to do.

So if you have any clue, link or code it would be really nice thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the subclassed cell's `accessoryType` or `accessoryView` property? When touched, perhaps the `-tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method could be used to trigger some animation on the content of the custom cell's `contentView`.